# TRRS connector schematic

Tags: connector, trrs

Can somebody explain the following schematic and how can I use this connector with a TRRS cable:
I can see pins 2 and 6 are connected but I don't understand why there are still 4 pins left instead of 3 (TRRS connectors have only 4 contacts, not 5).
I also don't understand why pins 4 and 5 point up.

This is the [schematic](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Korean-Hroparts-Elec-PJ-602-6A_C145810.pdf) for the [PJ6026A](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Audio-Video-Connectors_Korean-Hroparts-Elec-PJ-602-6A_C145810.html).

Thank you.

UPDATE:
I think pins 1 and 3 point down because they are on one side of the connector, pins 4 and 5 point up because they are on the opposite side.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 and 4 are the same length so both connect to the tip.

```
T   3, 4
R   5
R   1
S   2, 6
```

That arrangement probably helps keep the plug straight in the socket as the forces are better balanced.

Comment: When a connector is plugged in, 3 and 4 will also be shorted together. This allows the device to determine when a plug is inserted.